# Simulate DragAndDrop of file into WPF window

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop

In my application i support drag and drop, this part of the code is working correctly when the user does it.

Now, i would like to allow people the ability to create custom scripts (for testing, and for debugging etc.) so i need a way to simulate the effect of dragging a file from windows file, into my application.

I have create a command:

```
MCommandsManager.CreateEventSimulationCommand<string[]>(this, "Shell", "DragAndDrop", (o) => DragAndDropHandler(o));
```

that can be called from a script like this:

```
 menu.simulate.draganddrop(c:\temp.jpg)
```

this calls my function:

```
     private object DragAndDropHandler(string[] o)
     {
     string filePath = o[0];
     if (File.Exists(filePath))
        {
        var data = new DataObject(DataFormats.FileDrop, o);
        DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this, data, DragDropEffects.Move | DragDropEffects.Copy);
        }
     return false;
     }
```

Oddly enough, when i execute this the temp file that i want opens inside my VS... and not inside my application.

Is there another API that i should be looking at.  It doesnt seem like DragDrop has what i need.

Comment: Have you tried leveraging UIA?

Comment: never heard of it, i guess i have some homework to do.

Comment: Accessibility APIs built into all standard windows controls can cover a lot of needs re: top-level GUI testing. Ramp up can be a little tricky at times, though, so it's not a universally good fit. You'll want to look into UIA and MSAA. :)